# Asp.net MVC5 website hosting on godady: System.Security.SecurityException

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config

I have created a website using Visual Studio 2015 with .netframework 4.5.2. The website is working fine in local machine but when I have uploaded the publish the website in Godaddy.  First I got the error custom Error needs to be off.I added the tag to fix this.

```
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
```

Then I get the Trust permission error "System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed". 
I googled and find out that the trust level needs to be set to full in web.config and asp.net setting in the server.
I set the CAS trust level to full in the Godaddy server and web.config set butit still did not work.

```
<trustLevel name="Full" policyFile="internal"/>
```

I am getting Internal server error.
I tried again and still same error.

```
<securityPolicy>
    <trustLevel name="Full" policyFile="internal"/>
 </securityPolicy>
```

I am not sure what changes I need in web.config file to work. Please find my web.config

```
<configuration>
 <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=SAFIRE\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Hotel;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="MvcMailer.BaseURL" value="" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>    
 <authentication mode="None" />    
 <customErrors mode="Off"/>
 <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <trustLevel name="Full" policyFile="internal" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp from="xxx">
        <network host="smtpout.europe.secureserver.net" port="25" userName="xxx" password="xxx" />
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
<system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
</system.codedom>
```

Am I missing some setting for web.config?

Answer (score 0):

you have to clear out system.Codedom
remove that section and add `<system.codedom/>`

this worked for me

Answer (score -1):

You should do couple of things to identify the problem

1) Check if the connection string contains the "integrated Security=true", if true then it means website trying to connect the Database with windows credentials, try not to use windows credentials

2) if this not solves the problem then turn on the custom errors temporarily, and then browse the website, it should give some meaningful error message

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. You can post an answer once the problem is clear. If the problem isn't clear, post a comment asking for clarification.

Comment: I did change the connection string to the connection string from the Godaddy  data base and turned on the custom error. Still showing the same Error. 500 internal server error.

Comment: I updated the we.config with   <securityPolicy><trustLevel name="Full" policyFile="internal"/> </securityPolicy>. Now I am getting 403 forbidden error.You do not have permission to access this document. I guess this is a trust level issue not sure where I am going wrong after stating the trust level to full.

Comment: Instead on your code, you need to try to give full permission to your folder. Please test.